# How to calculate volume of solid of revolution of a polygon with boost::geometry?

Tags: c++, geometry, computational-geometry, volume, boost-geometry

Given a polygon like:

```
boost::geometry::model::polygon shape;
```

How to calculate the volume of the solid or the rotation of `shape` against the OX axis?

Answer (score 1):

The volume subtended by a revolving line segment around `OX` (i.e. a section of a conic surface) is given by `2π (Y0²+Y0.Y1+Y1²)(X1 - X0)/3`. To obtain the complete volume, you just accumulate the contributions of all edges of the polygon (some of the terms will be negative).

CAUTION: this only works with a polygon on the positive side of `OX`. If necessary, clip it.

Comment: I was hoping to obtain the volume by a single `boost::geometry` function call, rather than calculating it manually.